# unix e linux são palavras reservadas?

Tags: c, palavras-reservadas

Mesmo não declarando as variáveis `unix` e `linux` e mesmo sem incluir nada em meu `teste.c` compilando com o `GCC` no Linux tenho:

**Compilação**

```
gcc teste.c -o teste
```

**Execução**

```
./teste
```

**Saída**

> Unix e Linux valem 1

**Código**

```
main()
{
        if(linux * unix)
                puts("Unix e Linux valem 1");
}
```

São palavras reservadas da linguagem? Porque as duas valem 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não são palavras reservadas mas sim macros pré-definidas quando o compilador está a ser executado em ambiente Linux/Unix.

Experimenta, na linha de comando, executar o seguinte comando para listar todas essa macros:

```
gcc -dM < /dev/null
```

As duas palavras linux e unix apresentam a seguinte definição:

```
gcc -dM < /dev/null | grep linux

#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define linux 1

gcc -dM < /dev/null | grep unix 
#define __unix__ 1
#define __unix 1
#define unix 1
```

O standard ANSI C de 1989 introduziu regras que obrigam a que o nome de uma macro seja iniciado por dois underscores ou por um underscore seguido por uma letra maisculas.

Podes dizer que o gcc, por defeito, "não respeita" essas mesmas regras, significando que não podes fazer algo como

```
int main() {

   int unix = 10;

}
```

Isto irá gerar a seguinte mensagem:

```
error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
  int unix = 10;
```

Como o @pmg indicou na sua resposta, podes alterar este comportamente usando as opções:

```
gcc -std=c90 -pedantic
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic
```

Answer (score 2):

O `gcc` é um compilador para várias linguagens.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards

> By default, GCC provides some extensions to the C language that on rare occasions conflict with the C standard. See [Extensions to the C Language Family](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions). ...

Da maneira que o chamaste ele é um compilador para "GNUC89".

Em "GNUC89" os simbolos `unix` e `linux` estão definidos como `1` na tua implementação.

Para usares o gcc como compilador de C11 (a versão mais recente do Standard), invoca-o assim

```
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic ...
```